# Where best to put the generator.close()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I buildt This class this morning and it works sweet and is tight but since it works by calling a fresh generator every time I'm concerned I'm leaving a bunch in memory. I'd love to do it right after the yield statement with a finally. It would seem a little cleaner.

```
class Enter:
    def __init__(self,Entries, container=[], keyName = "Key", valueName = "Value"):
        self.Dict = {}
        self.Entries = Entries
        self.container = container
        self.keyName = keyName
        self.valueName = valueName

    def gen(self,dis):
            print(dis)
            yield input("Entry: ")

    def enter(self):
        for ea in range(self.Entries):
            print("\nPlease input a", self.keyName, "then a", self.valueName)
            x = next(self.gen("\nEnter a " + self.keyName + ":"))
            y = next(self.gen("\nEnter a " + self.valueName + ":"))
            self.Dict.update({x:y})
        retrun self.Dict

    def enterList(self):
        lst = []
        for ea in range(self.Entries):
            print("\nSome Message")
            x = next(self.gen("\nEnter: "))
            lst.append(x)
        if self.container == ():
            lst = tuple(lst)         
        return lst

Dictionary = Enter(Entries = 2, keyName = "First Name", valueName="LastName").enter()

print(Dictionary)

output = Enter(Entries = 3, container= () ).enterList()

print(output)
```

Comment: It's a little odd that you use generators at all. Why not have a regular function call and a return statement?

Comment: Like every object, generators will be subject to be released by the garbage collection as soon as there is no reference left pointing to it. Since you only call `next()` on each generator, you have no reference, so they won’t stay in memory indefinitely. They’ll be released eventually. You are waisting a lot of boilerplate memory for those generators though. If you only have a single value, don’t use a generator.

Comment: How much boiler plate?  I've worked on it some more, renamed it Entry, and now it returns a list, tuple, or dictionary  with just just one more small method.  I only added one argument to def __init__.  I'm new so I haven't seen anything else that would do this with such little code.
I still would like to take out the indiv. generators out manually, but if the scale of boilerplate involved is too much and/or there is something clearly better I'd like to be clear on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your code style I'd say you're a Java programmer giving python a whirl.

Welcome to python, you chose the right version :)

One of the very cool things about python is that you rarely have to be concerned with memory leaks. python uses reference counting to make sure inaccessible objects get garbage collected.

in `x = next(self.gen("\nEnter a " + self.keyName + ":"))` 3 important things happen:

- `gen(self,dis)` is called, returning a generator object
- `next(gen)` moves the generator to the next yield statement `yield input("Entry: ")` and returns the yielded value. *note that it does **not** cause the generator to exit as it has yet to reach a return or the end of the function. Calling next(gen) again would do this (and raise `StopIteration`)*
- The returned value is bound to `x` whilst the generator object has become inaccesible (it has no variable left which is bound to it). The generator object is therefor deleted by the python garbage collector.

This said, I would agree with others saying that a generator is inappropriate for this application. Not because of overhead - I highly doubt that generator instantiation would cause any noticable overhead in most applications - but because the application is **very** simple.

In addition the code will be easier to read if simplified to

```
def gen(self,dis):
        print(dis)
        return input("Entry: ")

def enter(self):
    for ea in range(self.Entries):
        print("\nPlease input a", self.keyName, "then a", self.valueName)
        x = self.gen("\nEnter a " + self.keyName + ":")
        y = self.gen("\nEnter a " + self.valueName + ":")
        self.Dict.update({x:y})
    retrun self.Dict
```

Generally python is best when written [idiomatically](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M)

Comment: That was great, thank you! I am in general new to programming.   I happened on, putting the input function on the generator this morning and found it pretty neat.  Didn't dawn on me that I could just put on a return. I do read a lot but also spend a good amount of time, 'poking it with a stick' and seeing what happens.   Still I've heard mention about the overhead of generators but I have no idea about the relative scale of that.  I did read the doc and it mentioned the need to close, so the question.  Thanks for video link.  Best of all the answer in code was a snap to pick up on.

Answer (score 5):

Every generator object has a lot of overhead just for managing the state and everything. Unless you need a generator for the right reasons, you should avoid them. In your case, you are only yielding a single item, your generator cannot produce more, and that one value is immediately available at no cost. So using a generator is completely wrong here.

Instead, you can just write your `enter` function efficiently like this without any overhead:

```
def enter(self):
    for ea in range(self.Entries):
        print("\nPlease input a", self.keyName, "then a", self.valueName)
        x = input("\nEnter a " + self.keyName + ":")
        y = input("\nEnter a " + self.valueName + ":")
        self.Dict[x] = y
    return self.Dict
```

Comment: More generally, "Unless you need a *language-feature* for the right reasons, you should avoid it"

Comment: That code helps me understand, thank you.  I'm still unclear as to the difference in scale.  I do understand that generators do have in general more overhead involved.  How much and if it is significant is still a question I'd like to be clear on.

Comment: @ poke.  I found your comment inappropriate and would appreciate you removing your self from commenting on my posts so I do not have to spend my time doing so.

Comment: @user3163030 I’m really sorry for spending *my time* answering your question.